# Screen resolution on RPI3B+ too small when connected with Teamviewer + crashes

Tags: pi-3, remote, vnc, headless, raspberry-pi-os-bullseye

I am running 3xRPI4 and 1xRPI3B+ with the bullseye release from 30.10.2021 and after the update function from raspi-config.

The RPI4 work fine, however, I cannot fix the small screen resolution of the RPI3B+, please see screenshot below.

Additionally,
a) after connecting and clicking 2-3 times (on explorer or anywhere else) the connection freezes and I need to reconnect after one minute again (without rebooting the RPI).
b) the connection takes were long to initialize

My fix attempts were:

1. Editing /usr/bin/startlxde-pi according to [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/raspberry_pi/comments/qs6vpf/raspberryos_bullseye_very_laggy_with_teamviewer/), otherwise it's too laggy to use TV on the RPIs.
2. Set fixed resolution of 1920x1080
3. Added the following to /boot/config.txt:
   hdmi_force_hotplug=1
   hdmi_ignore_edid=0xa5000080
   disable_overscan=1

[image]

Comment: `according to here` what did you *actually* do from "there"

Comment: Does this apply?  https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=154832